# How to get mailchimp list name and list id using php

Tags: php, mailchimp

How to get mailchimp list name and list unique id?
I have tried to get it by using mailchimp api but it show the blank result.

Comment: Please follow the instructions available here https://github.com/mailchimp/mcapi2-php-examples